# Can the shadows be touched while invisible?

Tags: babylon-5

Think the question says it all..

I am wondering when the shadows can't be seen but are present do they still have substance and can be touched?  or are they in a different phase or something?

Comment: They can be shot

Comment: I just answered [a question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154273/38235) with the exact same concern.  It's not answered in the show, but they are energy beings, not just demonic black spiders.